# How can I fix the positioning of this AccordionDetails using Material UI/Grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Here's the wireframe of what I'd like:

[image]

And here's what I have coded using Material UI's Accordion component.

[image: Coded]

And here's the code for the AccordionDetails, which is what my question is about. Specifically, my question is: how do I put FilterC/the switch/FilterD onto one line, and the slider onto the next line in an AccordionDetails component?

```
<AccordionDetails>
  <FilterC/>
  <h1>Filter D</h1>
  <Switch/>
  <Filter D/>
</AccordionDetails>
```

I think I need to either add a class to AccordionDetails, and use FlexBox or alternatively use Grid somehow. But, I'm positively stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Can you share a stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that AccordionDetails component has a display flex by default, so I would Personally add a class to it and give it a "direction: column" so all the items stack up under each other. then on each row, you can have any kind of layout like another grid with "direction: row" which is the default.
also, note that you can make a grid component a container & an item at the same time, but I had found some weird behavior with that so I usually stick with explicit grid containers & items
‍‍‍

```
.accordionDetails: {
flexDirection: "column"
}
```

...

```
<AccordionDetails className={classes.accordionDetails}>
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container>
      <FilterC/>
      <h1>Filter D</h1>
      <Switch/>
      <Filter D/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Slider/>
  </Grid>
</AccordionDetails>
```

Comment: For future readers of this answer, AccordionDetails is no longer display: flex by default: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/22809. So you also need to add display: flex.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using styled components an equivalent answer is :

```
const AccordionDetailsColumnFlex = styled(AccordionDetails)`
    flex-direction: column;
`;

<AccordionDetailsColumnFlex>
 <Grid item>
    <Grid container>
      <FilterC/>
      <h1>Filter D</h1>
      <Switch/>
      <Filter D/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Slider/>
  </Grid>
</AccordionDetailsColumnFlex>
```

(TypeScript flavour styled component)